# What is λ in the context of Spatial Point Statistics?

Tags: spatial, point-estimation

What is a small lambda λ in the context of spatial point statistics and how do I calculate it for a given set of point?

Specifically I am trying to calculate it for different sets of observations of *Sequoia* trees in a small square area.

The screenshot of the trees:

[image: Sequoia Trees UA]

Comment: Number of points per unit area. So, count the number of points and divide by the total area. Same principle, regardless of software.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so my area is 23mX23m and I count 62. The λ is then 62/23=2.695652173913043?

Comment: No. Your area is 23 m $\times$ 23 m = 529 m$^2$. The dimensions are count per unit area, not count per unit length. The units in your case are number per square metre. See e.g. http://www.amazon.com/Quantitative-Ecology-Second-Measurement-Scaling/dp/0126278652 or any basic account of dimensions and units.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the reference for the book, I will look for it in the library. To conclude, the answer for the example given is λ = 62/529 = 0.1172022684310019 ? In other words 0.11 trees per square meter?

Comment: Sounds right. Seems plausible. Presumably you know the trees in question. Does it make sense to you? Average is about 1 tree in 10 m$^2$.

Comment: To be completely honest, I am not sure. I'm a student - far from a Quantitative Ecology professional. I have a screenshot I will add to the post

Comment: You don't need to be a quantitative ecology professional here: I'm not. That kind of density is plausible for many species, but not all. Age is also important.

Comment: I don't know enough about _Sequoia_ to comment further. If these are not your measurements, a literature or internet source should be given.

Comment: Thanks for that. The source is Ripley but as I understand this is a modified version of the observations to create different patterns

Comment: "Ripley": I happen to know that Brian Ripley is a well-known statistician who has written several books and papers. Many people here but not all will know that too. But that doesn't  pin down the reference.. Let's try this in reverse. I am currently reading Greenacre. Which book or paper is that?

Comment: It might be added that the original source is Strauss (in a paper in 1975) and the plot you show is a subset of this data extracted by Ripley for his influential paper in 1977. This data is available in the R package `spatstat` as `redwood` (1977 subset) and as `redwoodfull` (1975 full dataset).